# Event Slide Toggle stops after page changed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slidetoggle

I'm working on my Rails project. I have a header dropdown menu and SlideToggle is working fine unless I change the page. Then it works again if I refresh the page (F5).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

You'll be able to resolve like this:

```
var load_new = function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});

$(document).on("page:load ready", load_new);
```